# Stackoverflow with WPF Calendar when using DisplayDateStart binding

Tags: wpf

I have a little problem.

My small WPF Project with a normal Calendar get a System.StackOverflowException Exception, when I try to use  `DisplayDateStart="{Binding DisplayDate.Date.Date.Now, ElementName=MeinCalendar, Mode=OneWay}"` Binding.

I can start my Project without any errors, but when I click the Back and Next button a few times.Calendar throws the `System.StackOverflowException` Exception.

When I start the project without Binding this Exception is not more there.

How can I fix this bug?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMVVMtest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Calendar  x:Name="calendar" DisplayDateStart="{Binding DisplayDate.Date.Now, ElementName=calendar, Mode=OneWay}" ></Calendar>
```

Comment: Real words and real sentences please.   Try Mode=TwoWay and have a setter

Comment: I try :) i don't speek english soo good as you. Mode=TwoWay is not possible bc the DisplayDate.Date.Now ist protected.I can only read not save

Comment: I have the solution:
<Calendar x:Name="calendar" DisplayDateStart="{Binding DisplayDate.Today, ElementName=calendar, Mode=OneWay}"  ></Calendar>
The problem was bc DisplayDate.Date.Now have time value which
refresh evry 3 sec.
Today value make this refresh not